# get facebook post data using facebook post url facebook graph api laravel php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and Facebook Graph api v2.5.What i want to do is to get the facebook post data from the facebook post url or facebook post id from its url.

Here is what i have tried

```
$data = $this->fb->get('/https://web.facebook.com/fnkcrisp/photos/a.672814049531838.1073741830.608700929276484/885537761592798/',APP_ID.'|'.APP_SECRET);
$data = json_decode($data->getBody());
    echo $data->og_object->id;
```

but it does not give me the facebook post id so that i can use post id to get facebook post data like this

```
$post_data = $this->fb->get(''.$post_id.'?fields=created_time,full_picture,message,shares,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1),permalink_url', APP_ID.'|'.APP_SECRET);
```

but it only give me the object id if i request data using the object id then it gives me only likes and comments

```
$_data = $this->fb->get($og_objectid,APP_ID.'|'.APP_SECRET);
        $_data = json_decode($_data->getBody());
```

kindly help me how can i fetch facebook post data using its facebook post url or how can i get facebook post id from its url.

Comment: The API doesn’t use full URLs to identify objects. You will need to extract the necessary id(s) yourself from that URL first. (Or you go the other way, and read a user’s feed or photos first – then you will get the correct ids directly from the API.)

Comment: @CBroe can you please kindly tell me how can i get the necessary id(s) by myself...

Comment: If you want to get them from the URL you have shown, you’ll need to parse the relevant parts out yourself.